# How to set the "ulimit -c unlimited" in android "init.rc"

Tags: android, init, boot, coredump

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md

From the above link, I found that there is "**setrlimit**" used to "**Set the rlimit for a resource**".

I tried to enable the core dump during the android booting by adding the command "**setrlimit 4 8024 8024**".

But if check the "**cat /proc/self/limits**" value, it is not reflecting. The **soft limit** value is still set to "**0**".

Can you please let me know how to set the core dump value (similar to "ulimit -c unlimited") to unlimited during android init.rc?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this instead,just include

```
<sys/resource.h>
```

to use getrlimit and setrlimit to extend max open software file node.
like this,

```
getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &limit);
```